# Chrome Portable on read only device: Suppress read only warning

Tags: windows, google-chrome, readonly, portable-applications, kiosk-mode

I'm making a windows app for a client using Chrome in kiosk mode. They'd like to burn the project to CD. While this works fine with chrome portable on a read access device it doesn't with a read only device. A warning pops up asking to temporarily copy it to the local drive to run from there. Clicking yes allows the program to work but i'd like to suppress this as they won't want to see it every time. Is there a way for me suppress the warning or cache to the cd before it's burned?

I need to use chrome, not another portable browser. I could be being naive and they're may be a better option than using Portable apps chrome download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around user policies you can try a pretty software does what you want.
http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-2-desktop-app-converter/4527199

This uses chrome engine and creates kiosk like portable engine for your given URL or local files. It makes pages looking like windows application. Hope helps.
Note: I'm not the author :)

Comment: gonna bump this as an answer cos I need to get round chrome's policy. Thank you.

Comment: You welcome.
I couldn't offer a free solution but at least affordable $18

Answer (score 2):

I asked the same question on the Portable apps website and got this response. It worked great although take note of the distribution license.

---

Add a text file called GoogleChromePortable.ini in your GoogleChromePortable folder that says

[GoogleChromePortable]
RunLocally=true

this will make it copy the profile to the temp folder on the computer and run from there whether it's in read only place or not.

also notice Johns reminder in Pyromaniac's thread (http://portableapps.com/node/37168#comment-207403) - giving someone, especially a "customer" a copy of Google Chrome, Portable or otherwise, is illegal, don't do it.

---

Link to forum
http://portableapps.com/node/37164#comment-207482

---

I've investigated the license agreement and found this

21.2 Subject to the Terms, and in addition to the license grant in Section 9, Google grants you a non-exclusive, non-transferable license to reproduce, distribute, install, and use Google Chrome solely on machines intended for use by your employees, officers, representatives, and agents in connection with your business entity, and provided that their use of Google Chrome will be subject to the Terms.

So legal as long as it's kept internal. Works great if anyone ever stumbles on this question. Chrome makes an awesome portabl app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [**link**](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) to where I got something that worked for me.

In the **Support** section, there is a performance note that advices copying **GoogleChromePortable.ini** from the `GoogleChromePortable\Other\Source` directory to the `GoogleChromePortable` directory and editing it to set `RunLocally=true` in order to increase performance, well this sorts out the warning that pops up.

However take note of the privacy implications of doing this as also stated in the same section.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Chromium` (portable) which also includes `chromedriver` from chromium snapshots page. Pick one with the biggest number (scroll down):

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/